# Samba4 & Active Directory Kerberos [Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'INTERNAL.CORP.COM' while getting initial credentials

Tags: kerberos, samba4

Yesterday I configured an Active Directory Server using Arch Linux and Samba 4 following this [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba_4_Active_Directory_domain_controller).

I even added a client to the domain and was able to log in successfuly on my client. After a restart it no longer works, I can't use Microsoft RSAT anymore and I tracked down this problem to the `kinit administrator@INTERNAL.CORE.COM` instruction which returns:

> Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'INTERNAL.CORP.COM' while getting initial credentials

Trying to solve my problem I tried googling around and found [this](http://research.imb.uq.edu.au/~l.rathbone/ldap/kerberos.shtml):

> kinit(v5): Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm while getting initial credentials
>
> The application cannot find the kerberos server. Check firewall, DNS and /etc/hosts.

But, as pointed by the Arch Linux Tutorial posted adobe I tried some commands to test connection:

```
# host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.internal.corp.com.
# host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.internal.corp.com.
# host -t A core.internal.corp.com.  #core is my server hostname
```

Which returned:

```
_ldap._tcp.internal.corp.com has SRV record 0 100 389 core.internal.corp.com.
_kerberos._udp.internal.corp.com has SRV record 0 100 88 core.internal.corp.com.
core.internal.corp.com has address 192.168.0.75
```

As you can see on my second command it seems that I actually can reach the kerberos service.

Here are some of my config files:

/etc/krb5.conf (copied from /var/lib/samba/private/krb5.conf as pointed on the tutorial )

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = INTERNAL.CORP.COM
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.0.75
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search internal.corp
namserver 127.0.0.1
```

My server hostname is `CORE`.
My NetBIOS Domain is `CORP`.
My DNS Domain is `internal.corp.com`

I'm out of ideas, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Searching a little bit more I found a solution to my problem. As posted [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2252604&p=13169923#post13169923), all I needed to do was changing my samba configuration:

/etc/samba/smb.conf
 Where I added this line into the `[global]` section.

`server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, dns, s3fs`

Comment: Saved my day :)

Comment: Saved on 4.12.0 but had to remove the line on 4.13.2 ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, but it is very important to set the `nameserver` in  `/etc/resolv.conf` to the same IP as samba ad dc like stated here:

```
The 'nameserver' you set in '/etc/resolv.conf' must be an AD DC, otherwise the join will not be able to find the KDC.
```

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Joining_a_Samba_DC_to_an_Existing_Active_Directory#Configuring_DNS